# How to pass value from AngluarJS to MVC Controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working with AngularJS and I am trying to pass a value from the Angular into the Controller. This is what my AngularJS Script File looks like:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        {
            function startTime() {
                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                var s = today.getSeconds();
                // add a zero in front of numbers<10
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);
                return (h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
                t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
            }
            $scope.name = startTime();
        }            
    });
 </script>
```

So from that I am able to get the time through calling $scope.name. But I want to pass that variable into the controller. The way I was thinking of doing it was to pass it in an Html.BeginForm as a parameter but that's not working. This is my BeginForm:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Bob", "Home", new { Time = ng-model="name" },  
FormMethod.Post, null))
    {

        <p>Name:</p> <input style="color:black;" ng-model="name">
        <h1 style="color:black;">You entered: {{name}}</h1>
        <button type="submit" style="color:black;">Submit</button>
    }
</div>
```

Right now I have the input box there just so I could make sure that it's passing the right value, and it is. But in the BeginForm it's not allowing Time to equal the value being passed from the AngularJS. How would I be able to pass that value to the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a hidden field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bob", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input name="time" type="hidden" ng-value="name" />
    <button type="submit" style="color:black;">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but what I am trying to accomplish is pass the value of ng-value back into the Controller without an input box. I like your idea of doing a hidden field but I'm trying to find out how to do that (set a ViewBag to the ng-value...but how, or some other way).